# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. [ Raspberry Pi Python 3.10.9 ]

Tags: debian, python, ssl, raspberry-pi, python3

I am using a raspberry pi and trying to update from Python3.9 to Python3.10.9

I use the following commands:

```
    sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev
    sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.9/Python-3.10.9.tgz
    tar -xzvf Python-3.10.9.tgz
    cd Python-3.10.9
    ./configure --enable-optimizations
    sudo make altinstall
    sudo rm /usr/bin/python
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python
```

The end result is I have a Python3.10.9 in my home folder, when I use `python -V` it displays the correct version

The problem is I have to install packages into pip 22.3.1 as the previous versions were for older versions of python. When I try to directly download pip 22.3.1 the terminal informs me that version is already installed with the Python 3.10.9 installation.

When I run `pip -V` it informs me it is using version 20 for python 3.9

If I install packages using pip3.10 instead of pip I get the error from the title

an example installation

```
sudo pip3.10 install mysql-connector-python==8.0.32
```

Does anyone know if I am missing some more dependencies to get it to work? Please let me know if i can provide more details, thanks!